# Laravel 4: authenticate login from Codeigniter DB

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-4

I have Database created by Codeigniter included "users" table, the problem is "password" in this table hash by Codeigniter and I need to authenticate login using Laravel 4,

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

how to rewrite Auth::attempt to accept Codeigniter HASH?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use same hash function used in `Codeigniter` (it's sha1 by default), then you can login the user manually if the password matches, so instead of using `Auth::attempt`:

```
if($user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->where('password', '=', sha1($password))->first()){
    Auth::login($user);
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```